# How to restart supervisord program after some interval?

Tags: php, supervisord

Is it possible to configure supervisord to restart programs after specified time?

Let's say I have a CLI PHP script that can potentially hang and stop responding. Is it possible to restart all instances of this application after 2 hours? Otherwise there should be a situation when application is running, but it is hanged state (i.e. does not do any work and and does not respond to any signals).

Comment: I don't know supervisord but you can write start time in a file with PHP, and check with a crontab (maybe each 5mn?) and if start time is more than 2 hours?

Comment: In this case supervisord is useless

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a rough around the edges solution (perhaps someone can tidy it up), but as supervisord has supervisorctl you can run this to restart all jobs after X hours (as a cronjob on the supervisord server)

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
excludedprocesses=(somejob someotherjob)

for f in `supervisorctl status | awk '{print $1}' `;  do  
        echo "found $f"

        if [[ ${excludedprocesses[*]} =~ $f ]]
        then
                echo "Exluding $f as a restart candidate"
        else
                status=`supervisorctl status $f | awk '{print $2}'`

                if [ "$status" == "RUNNING" ] ; then
                        echo "$f is running"

                        uptimedays=`supervisorctl status $f | grep day`
                        timepart=`supervisorctl status $f | awk '{print $NF}' | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`
                        if [[ -n $uptimedays ]] |[[ $timepart -gt 1 ]] ;
                        then
                                echo "Restarting $f due to uptime"
                                `supervisorctl restart $f`
                        fi  

                fi  
        fi  
        echo ""
done
```